# Unicode Character from Code in String (Obj-C)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unicode

I have a unicode hex value in an NSString - how do I output the character; here's what I have:

```
NSLog(@"\U0001D000");

NSMutableString *hexString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"0001D000"];
[hexString insertString:@"\\U" atIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@", hexString);
```

The first NSLog outputs the character; the second just produces the output "\U0001D000"

I've tried lots of combinations and am at a loss - for example, I tried

```
NSLog(@"\U%@", hexString);
```

But this gives a complier error, as it is looking for a string of numbers after the \U

Comment: The reason the first `NSLog` works is because `\U0001D000` is an escape character processed by the compiler. The second is just a string that happens to have a slash and a 'U' and some hex digits. It's the same as any other escape character. If you did `[hexString insertString:@"\\n" atIndex:0];` you know you wouldn't get a new line. To do this kind of thing you have to use a library or something that will process escape characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your character requires a surrogate pair (U+10000 to U+10FFFF), use `CFStringGetSurrogatePairForLongCharacter` to convert the Unicode code point into a UTF-16 surrogate pair, and then `-initWithCharacters:length:` to convert it into an NSString. For example:

```
UniChar c[2];
CFStringGetSurrogatePairForLongCharacter(0x1D000, c);
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:c length:2];
```

For other characters (`CFStringGetSurrogatePairForLongCharacter` returns `FALSE`), you can skip the conversion and go straight to `-initWithCharacters:length:`.