# Unicode Surrogate Pairs in IOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, unicode, ios6, surrogate-pairs

I have a surrogate pair, example below:

\ud83d\ude04

I want to know how to get the corresponding value value like "1F604"

Any sample code ?

Any help will be appreciable ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062923/unicode-character-from-code-in-string-obj-c

Comment: @iPatel thank you for your reply..I am new in iPhone dev.So I dont know how to use the above code.Can you please help

Answer (score 1):

To convert a surrogate pair into a UTF-32 character or codepoint value, use [`CFStringGetLongCharacterForSurrogatePair`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringGetLongCharacterForSurrogatePair). For example:

```
UniChar high = 0xd83d;
UniChar low = 0xde04;

UTF32Char c = CFStringGetLongCharacterForSurrogatePair(high, low);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.But then in my case how to pass \ud83d\ude04
to 'high' and 'low'

Comment: then I am getting 128516 not as "1F604" ?

Comment: `128516` is the same as `0x1F604` in [hex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).